# Using dates with PHP CLI

Tags: php, function, command-line-interface

I recently started using PHP and I am learning how to use it in the CLI for now.

I am working on a script that calculates the premium rate of a customer based on their date of birth and cover amount chosen.

The user has to call the script in CLI and pass 2 params to the script. The 1st param is their DOB and the 2nd param is the Cover amount.

I found a piece of code that works for me but because I am new to PHP, I do not yet understand why it works.

Can someone please break this code down for me and explain what is happening.

```
//date in mm/dd/yyyy format; or it can be in other formats as well
  $dob = $argv[1];

//explode the date to get month, day and year
  $dob = explode("/", $dob);

  //get age from date or birth date
  $age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $dob[0], $dob[1], $dob[2]))) > date("md") ? ((date("Y") - $dob[2]) - 1) : (date("Y") - $dob[2]));
```

So right now my program works. But I don't understand the logic behind this block code. I literally started learning PHP yesterday :).

I love understanding why a thing works. I hat just copying and pasting with out knowing why.

Love you guys for helping to explain this.

Comment: You check the github repo here

Comment: https://github.com/Cornelius-Labuschagne/calculate-life-rates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read about below links from the documentation you will understand what this code does.

[argv](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

[explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

[date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

[mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)